# save directly to file and get filename using WWW::Mechanize

Tags: perl, out-of-memory, mechanize

I would normally save to a file using this:

```
$mech->save_content($mech->response->filename);
```

But due to some big files which cause "Out of memory" I have to use this instead:

```
$mech->get( $url, ":content_file"=>$tempfile );
```

How can I get the filename with the second method, or do I have to make one up?

I want the filename that would be returned in the response object: `$mech->response->filename`. I don't want to make up my own filename.

Answer (score 2):

The `:content_file` option [is inherited from LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#get) and behaves in the same way. You don't know the file beforehand.

You *could* do a HEAD request to check the filename, and then do a GET request.

Alternatively, have a look at [the lwp-download utility](https://metacpan.org/pod/lwp-download) that ships with LWP::UserAgent. It provides exactly what you need. You could use it directly, or lift the stuff you want out of it. A WWW::Mechanize object can be dropped into this code and will behave exactly the same as the LWP::UserAgent one.

Comment: I want the filename that would be returned in the response object: `$mech->response->filename`.  I don't want to make up my own filename.

Comment: @CJ7 updated. I also just submitted [a PR to Mech](https://github.com/libwww-perl/WWW-Mechanize/pull/320) to change that `$tempfile` to `$filename` so it's consistent with the LWP docs.

Comment: I have to do this: `$mech->get( $url, ":content_file" => "$filename" )` Note the double quotes around `$filename`. Otherwise I get error `A :content_file value can't be a reference`. Do you know why?

Comment: The other thing I have noticed is that `$mech->head` doesn't work on relative URLs, even if the `$mech->base` is correct.

Comment: @CJ7 I have investigated the HEAD problem. It's never been implemented in Mech, so it's inherited from LWP, where there is no automatic handling of relative URLs. I'm preparing a PR now. If that gets approved we should have a new version soon.

Comment: I've fixed the `$mech->head` problem with https://github.com/libwww-perl/WWW-Mechanize/pull/321. Thanks for pointing it out @CJ7

Comment: @CJ7 I suspect your `"$filename"` issue is because the thing you have in $filename is not a filename, but maybe a file handle? Sticking it in quotes would stringify it, but it'd come out as `"SCALAR(0x1234)"` or `"GLOB(0x1234)"`

Comment: OK thanks, when will the fix of Mechanize be available from the `cpan` command ?

Comment: This is how I am getting $filename: `$filename = $mech->response->filename`.

Comment: @CJ7 it should be merged today, and I've asked that we release that today. If there are no issues with that, Olaf will probably release later today in a US timezone. I would expect it no sooner than 10 hours after this comment.

Comment: @CJ7 and it's been released as [version 2.04](https://metacpan.org/release/OALDERS/WWW-Mechanize-2.04/source/Changes). You can now install it from a CPAN mirror near you. :)